# Qt Creator release mode undefined references to std::out_of_range

Tags: qt, boost, mingw, release, qt-creator

I'm writing a small C++ program (with a GUI) with Qt Creator and compiling with MinGW. Everything works fine when I compile the project in debug mode but as soon as I move to release mode I get compiler errors:

```
undefined reference to 'std::out_of_range::~out_of_range()'         thread.cpp
```

When I click on the error I also get:

```
File not found: thread.cpp
```

I have looked through my Boost installation and found thread.cpp and it should be on the include path for my project.

Any ideas?

EDIT: Here is my .pro file:

```
#-------------------------------------------------
#
# Project created by QtCreator 2012-08-10T12:09:39
#
#-------------------------------------------------

QT       += core gui

TARGET = GeneDropWin
TEMPLATE = app

SOURCES += main.cpp \
    genedrop.cpp \
    mainbody.cpp \
    biofunctions.cpp \
    fileio.cpp \
    settings.cpp

HEADERS  += genedrop.h \
    geneclasses.h \
    paramclass.h \
    mainbody.h \
    biofunctions.h \
    fileio.h \
    geneclasses.h \
    settings.h

FORMS    += genedrop.ui \
    settings.ui

#Stuff I've added
INCLUDEPATH += "C:\\Program Files\\boost_1_50_0"
LIBS += -L"C:\\Program Files\\boost_1_50_0\\stage\\lib" -lboost_thread-mgw46-mt-1_50 -lboost_system-mgw46-mt-1_50 -lboost_date_time-mgw46-mt-1_50 -lboost_chrono-mgw46-mt-1_50
CONFIG += static \
    release

RESOURCES += \
    NIABLogo.qrc
```

Comment: This could be a problem with your .pro file, can you post it?

Comment: Sorry, I can't find any errors in the .pro file

Comment: Thanks for taking a look though :)

Comment: I have a sneaky suspicion my Boost libraries were built with MSVC yet I'm trying to compile with MinGW, could this have an effect?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, the problem is fixed but perhaps not completely understood. I fixed it by switching compiler to MSVC and changing the syntax for the linker options (e.g. -lboost_thread-mgw46-mt-1_50 -> -llibboost_thread-vc100-mt-1_50), compiles without an issue now. I will put forward my reasoning as to what I think may have been the problem but would appreciate a better answer if wrong:

1. Although I thought I had built the Boost libraries with MinGW when looking through the installation I found a number of folders mentioning msvc instead (e.g. ...boost\bin.v2\libs\date_time\build_msvc-10.0) which suggested to me that I had built it with MSVC.
2. The linker error claimed not to be able to find files associated with thread.cpp.
3. Looking at the thread folder of the build directory all the .obj and .lib files had msvc-10.0 folders in their path.
4. Thus I think that the MinGW compiler was looking for boost objects within a non-existent MinGW folder and so was failing. The fact that it worked under debug mode I guess relates to a less-constrained search for files.